# KeyGenerator error publishing TIBCO Web Service tu WSO2 UDDI

Tags: web-services, wso2, esb, tibco, uddi

I have a TIBCO Web Service that I want to publish on a WSO2 UDDI Server.
I configure the UDDI server on the `Infrastructure -> Servers` tab and I try to publish my application on the server.

I tried authenticating as `root`, `admin` and `uddi` but I always get the same error on WSO2 Side:

`TID: [0] [Greg] [2015-09-10 15:25:28,108]  INFO {org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain} -  Application {urn:uddi-org:v3_service}UDDIPublicationService#{urn:uddi-org:v3_service}save_tModel has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.juddi.v3.error.FatalErrorException: A Key Generator cannot be added for the root publisher. Try signing in as a different user {org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain}`

I tried to google a bit but I found only answers relevant to WSO2 API Server (which I don't have).
As far as I can remember, the WSO2 server doesn't have any custom configuration. This is the content of my `tomcat-user.xml`:

`<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="tomcat,manager,admin"/>
  <user username="root" password="root" roles="tomcat,manager,admin"/>
  <user username="uddi" password="uddi" roles="tomcat,manager,admin"/>`

Answer (score 0):

jUDDI doesn't allow you to create tModels key generators as the root user. Try it again using a different user name. This is probably in WSO2's configuration. Since it's probably an integration issue between the two, contact WS02 for support.

Alternatively, you can just download jUDDI and use the standalone server and use the the jUDDI web user interface to publish the service.

~ jUDDI PMC